# Access nested JSON with d3.json()

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have the following JSON

```
{
    "users":
 {
     "gender":
  {
      "tot":
   [
       {"label":"female", "value":6038},
       {"label":"male", "value":45228},
       {"label":"unknown", "value":32932}
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

I can load the file with `d3.json()` and visualise it via `console.log()` but I can't access the inner values and labels

Please consider the following script

```
d3.json("../data/m5s/sumStats.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d[0].users[0].gender[0].comment[0].label;
    }));
});
```

which returns at the third line

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Your label access code doesn't match your object definition.  That aside, where is x defined?

Comment: Objects don't have `map` method available. Thus, calling `data.map()` will produce "TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access the data in plain object notation:

```
d3.json("../data/m5s/sumStats.json", function(data) {
    // these are just examples, you don't need them
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.users);
    console.log(data.users.gender);
    console.log(data.users.gender.tot);

    // this is the important bit: we're not going over 'data' but over a sub-object of data:
    x.domain(data.users.gender.tot.map(function(d) { return d.label; }));
});
```

Comment: This is probably a different sort question altogether but if I have different nested objects which I want to visualise (`...gender.tot1`, `gender.tot2`, `gender.tot3`, etc.) in different charts with a `transition()` what's the best practice to follow? Should I load them in different variables with  `data1 = d3.json("../data/m5s/sumStats.json", function(data.users.gender.tot1) {return data;});` ?

Comment: you can use a for ... in loop over all the keys. In your case, that might look like this: `for (var key in data.users.gender) { console.log("this is your key: ", key); console.log("it contains: ", data.users.gender[key]); }` - sorry, no indentation in comments.