# Best approach to transitioning between different datasets with d3.js

Tags: json, d3.js

I am trying to build a bar chart which will allow the user to switch among different datasets (`tot1` and `tot2`) all included in one JSON file:

```
{
    "users":
 {
     "gender":
  {
      "tot1":
   [
       {"label":"female", "value":6038},
       {"label":"male", "value":45228},
       {"label":"unknown", "value":32932}
   ]
      "tot2":
   [
       {"label":"female", "value":6022},
       {"label":"male", "value":45328},
       {"label":"unknown", "value":12932}
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

I don't see how I should proceed. Following [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25322951/1707938) to a previous question I would need to select `tot1` or `tot2` when loading the data with `d3.json`. Of course the chart specs don't change when switching from `tot1` to `tot2`, so probably the right approach would be to compose the chart with a function which receives the data as an argument...

But if I try to load my data into variables I get an error

```
data1 = d3.json("../data.json", function(data) {return data.users.gender.tot;});
```

Comment: `d3.json` is asynchronous, so you have to save the data in the callback. There are many examples for switching between different data sets, e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5682158

Comment: First. you are using gender.tot -- not gender.tot1, as your data shows. Second, I recommend using a csv table format for data like you are using. that way, you won't need to use data nesting, which simplifies things.