# Using own JSON data in D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am following [this](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/choropleth_basic.html) `d3.js` example.

The data in this example is a `csv` file with the following structure:

| name | code | pop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Albania | ALB | 3153731 |
| United States | USA | 299846449 |
| Great Britain | GBR | 60244834 |

The data is loaded this way:

```
.defer(d3.csv, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world_population.csv", function(d) { data.set(d.code, +d.pop); })
```

Now I am trying to use my own modified data in JSON format.

`test.json`

```
 [{
        "name": "Albania",
        "code": "ALB",
        "pop": "0.111"
    },

    {
        "name": "United States",
        "code": "USA",
        "pop": "0.222"
    },
    {
        "name": "Great Britain",
        "code": "GBR",
        "pop": "0.333"
    }
 ]
```

To do this I just load my data instead of the dummy data:

```
var test = "test.json"

.defer(d3.json, test , function(d) { data.set(d.code, +d.pop);})
```

If I `console.log` the `csv` and the `json`, the resulting Objects look exactly the same.
But with the `json` no map is loaded and with the `csv` the map is loaded.

When I `console.log` the `csv` data like this:

```
.defer(d3.csv,  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world_population.csv", function(d) { console.log("DATA : " , d.code)
  data.set(d.code, +d.pop);})
```

I see the values in the `code` column in the console.

If I do the same with the `json`:

```
.defer(d3.json, test, function(d) { console.log("DATA : " , d.code)
    data.set(d.code, +d.pop);})
```

Nothing appears in the console.

So my question is, why can I access the values in the `csv` with `d.code` and `d.pop`, but not in the `json`?

Comment: Try to convert the json to csv ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I am planning to use an API that outputs JSON files, so this is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Try `defer(d3.json, test , function(d) { console.log('DATA: ', d); data.set(d.code, +d.pop);})` ... What do you see in the console?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I see  three Objects in this format: ````0: Object { name: "Albania", code: "ALB", pop: "0.111" }````

Comment: @gython data looks valid. Can you print the data you pass to `.selectAll(...).data(data_to_print).enter()`

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky The geoJSON data or the json data?

Comment: One correction: print `d.code` and `d.pop` here: `defer(d3.json, test , function(d) { console.log('DATA: ', d.code, d.pop); data.set(d.code, +d.pop);})`

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky  Then this shows up ``DATA:  undefined, function pop()``
​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong.

I cant use this part:

```
defer(d3.json, test, function(d) { console.log("DATA : " , d.code)
    data.set(d.code, +d.pop);})
```

Because I cant use a row function with `d3.json`.

More information in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322864/access-nested-json-with-d3-json)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that `d` in `defer(d3.json, test , function(d) {` is an array.

Try the following:

```
.defer(d3.json, test , function(d) { 
  d.forEach(({code, pop}) => data.set(code, +pop));
})
```

Comment: This solution returns  an object in this form: ``Object {  }
​
"$ALB": 0.111
​
"$GBR": 0.333
​
"$USA": 0.222`` while the òbject which is created by parsing the ``csv`` looks like this: ``Object { "$USA": 0.527, "$GBR": 0.46, "$ARE": 0.72 }``. In the first object which was created by parsing the ``json`` the brackets are empty.

Comment: @gython I'm not sure I understand it... What does it mean 'the brackets are empty' ? What do you get if you add `console.log('LEN: ', d.length, ' TYPE: ', Array.isArray(d))` ?

Comment: Sorry I wasnt very clear there. If I ``console.log`` the resulting ``map`` which is referenced by the ``data`` variable, the results for the ``json`` and ``csv`` file look different. If you look at my previous comment you see ``Object { }`` where the brackets are empty if I parse the ``json`` like in your proposed soloution. While in the second case the key-value pairs are IN the brackets.

Comment: regarding your proposed ``console.log``  I get the following result: ``LEN:  3  TYPE:  true``

Comment: Can you post a snippet or a link to fiddle / sandbox?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it with the external ``json`` file I am using?

Comment: I tried to add the ``json`` but it wont laod  https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=y1w5qTmInF

Comment: Make sure your bin is public, not private